# In Golang app, calling a C api that sends http request asynchronously and sends back response to Go callback function

Tags: c, multithreading, go, asynchronous, cgo

I have a Go application and some C API function that works asynchronously. This API function calls callbacks from some of those worker threads. Now, I want to pass Go functions as callbacks to that C API function. So, the Go callback functions would be called by the C function in the context of the worker threads, not known to the Go application. (e.g. C api sends http request to server and send back response to Go callback function).

The question is "Does Go support such scenario?" i.e. go routine that calls C api should wait for the response. Is it possible to handle such case?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried? Show some code - without it all people can do realistically is guess at what you're trying to do. Also check for duplicate questions, because I suspect a question such as this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37157379/1230836 should help you figure this out